# Download multiple pictures with symfony2

Tags: jquery, image, symfony, download, zip

I want to download multiple pictures as a zip in my symfony2 project, using jquery, but it's not working :(

I've read this: [Symfony2 : How to force download multiple images in one zip file with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987614/symfony2-how-to-force-download-multiple-images-in-one-zip-file-with-ajax)

but same issue, nothing happens :(

Here is my code, js function first:

```
function downloadZip() {
var searchIDs = $( ".picDashboardBox:checked" ).map( function( ) {
    return $(this).parent( ).parent( ).prev('td').prev('td').children( ).children( ).children( ).children( ).attr( 'src' );
} ).get( );
$.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: $( '#download' ).attr( 'url' ),
            data: { searchIDs: searchIDs },
            success: function(response) {
                return response;
            }
        }
    );
```

}

And here is my controller:

```
public function downloadPicturesAction( )
{
    $request = $this->get( 'request' );
    $pictures = $request->request->get( 'searchIDs' ) == null ? array( ) : $request->request->get( 'searchIDs' );

    $zip = new ZipArchive( );
    $filename = 'pictures.zip';
    if ( $zip->open( "/tmp/$filename", \ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | \ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE ) === TRUE )
    {
        foreach ( $pictures as $picture )
        {
            $tmp = explode( '/', $picture );
            $zip->addFromString( $tmp[count( $tmp ) - 1], file_get_contents( $picture ) );
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
    else
    {
        error_log( "can't create zip file to download" );
    }

    $response = new Response( );

    $response->headers->set( "Content-type", mime_content_type( "/tmp/$filename" ) );
    $response->headers->set( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=$filename" );
    $response->headers->set( "Content-length", filesize( "/tmp/$filename" ) );
    $response->headers->set( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
    $response->headers->set( "Expires", "0" );
    $response->send( );

    $response->setContent( readfile( "/tmp/$filename" ) );

    return $response;
}
```

I tried the code from the controller in pure php, it worked, I could download the zip, so I don't know what's wrong here (and I'm pretty bad with JS so maybe something is wrong ^^)

Thx :)

Arvi

Comment: If there are any error? Did you set 777 to folder where you upload image?

Comment: No, no error, but I managed to solve it. Instead of making the call via javascript, I use a form that makes the POST call to the controller, so now it works :)